# How do I modify that path that jupyter notebook uses upon startup?

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm able to import modules in my jupyter notebook as follows:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/library')
```

But I want to edit the files that jupyter notebook runs upon startup, so that I don't have to add a path for every single library.

How do I modify the path that jupyter notebook uses?

I tried modifying `PATH` but that didn't seem to work.  I did `export PATH=path/to/library:$PATH`.  And then I restarted the jupyter notebook but that didn't solve it.

How do I modify the path that jupyter notebook uses when it starts?

**EDIT**

The libraries that I'm unable to load are not modules that I've created - they are things like `numpy` and `scipy`.  I know where these libraries are in my system: `numpy` is at `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python` and `scipy` for some reason is at a different location `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`.  But I'm not able to import these when I boot up jupyter notebook, yet I can launch python in the terminal, and do `import scipy` or `import numpy` perfectly fine.

So, I assume that when I launch `python` from the terminal, it is using the correct environmental variable `PATH`.  However, when I launch jupyter notebook it is NOT able to do `import scipy` or `import numpy`.  So, I assume it is NOt using the correct environmental variable `PATH`.

How do I modify the latter so that it is like the former?

Comment: Correct me if I understand your query properly, you don't want to navigate to the folder where your python files are every time you run jupyter notebook. What I would do is open the folder and run the terminal command `jupyter notebook .` which would open the notebook with the files in that directory.

Comment: Not quite, although I'm glad you allowed me to clarify.  See the edit to the question:

Answer (score 1):

You could use os.chdir.OS module in Python provides functions for interacting with the operating system. OS, comes under Python’s standard utility modules.

```
import os      
os.chdir(r"path/to/library")
```

Comment: That will work, but I imagine is not an ideal solution because I would have to add that to every single notebook.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable to set the path used to locate modules, or the [PYTHONSTARTUP](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) environment variable to run the code appending to `sys.path`.

Comment: From the link you sent me, that seems like a great idea.  However, two questions:  1) Why is it that when I launch `python` from the terminal it works perfectly fine, but it does not work from a jupyter notebook?  2) Why is it that when I print `echo $PYTHONPATH` it doesn't print anything in the terminal?  How is it able to import things by launching `python` from the terminal without this variable set?

Comment: I suspect you used Conda or homebrew to install Jupyter.  Each of those will install a separate full Python, which wouldn't look at the system Python directories.  If that's what happened, I suggest removing the extra Python 2.7, Installing Python 3.7 from Python.org, an then installing numpy, pandas, and Jupyter into that, using pip3.

Comment: thanks.  However, two things:  1) . I cannot recall how I installed `jupyter`.  How do I figure out how to remove the unnecessary python 2.7?  And how do I know which one is unnecessary?  2) Still why is it that when I print `echo $PYTHONPATH` it doesn't print anything in the terminal? I cannot even figure out where it is getting the libraries from.

Comment: The Python in /System/Library is part of the OS, so you should leave that in place.  I don't know offhand how to find the other Python; looking in the Cobda or Homebrew docs (whichever one you might have used) may help.  In any case, if you install Python3 as I suggest, that will give you a Python that has all of the parts you need.  BTW, you will likely have to change the app that opens notebooks to the jupyter-notebook you install in your Python3 setup.